# BI - Cube Concept and MDX Query Help

Tags: business-intelligence, mdx, pentaho, mondrian

In a [Mondrian](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/mondrian/) Schema, I have a fact table for Sales, a dimension table Time and a dimension table Client.

I need to create a [Saiku](http://www.meteorite.bi/products/saiku) report where i can show how many clients joined per year. I have a the Time dimension and a join_date in Client (which DO NOT link to the Time Dimension key, is just a date field),.

If I create a cube adding Join_date as a Level of the Client Table, I wouldn't know how to filter that latter in the Saiku.

Does anyone know how is the best way to add JOIN_DATE on client? I just need a report: Clients that have joined to the company by year.

And how should `<Property>` work in cubes? When i tested using this `<Property>`, it was not visible in Saiku...

Comment: I'm having trouble decoding your question can you attempt to clarify please.

Comment: Ok i try to add more details, but if it doesen't help please tell me what you didn't get, the Objetive or the Scenario.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with help of MDX Custom filer on filter option when we generated report for cube.

there you write query regaring dimension table and fact table with help of select measures.[attribute] on rows from cube name where conditon apply  . and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. It might be even more helpful if you could describe why this works and how it would help - you'll probably attract more up votes that way as well :)